# Moving third-party windows in Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I try to support the program in Mac OS. The program must move one specific window of another program (the program must have more than 1 window open) to the specified monitor and expand it to the full screen. For Windows and Linux, this was implemented using a native API, but for MacOS it did not find an API to change Windows from its application. Could find a way to get the window ID but not change its state.

```
m_currentWindow->mac = 0;
CGWindowListOption option = kCGWindowListOptionAll;
CGWindowID id = 0;
CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCreate(option, id);
if(windows == nullptr)
{
  qCCritical(actOp) << "windows is null";
  return;
}
CFArrayRef desc = CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(windows);
if(desc == nullptr)
{
  qCCritical(actOp) << "windows description is null";
  return;
}
CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(desc);
qCDebug(actOp) << "finded " << count << " window";
QList<quint32> allWindows;
for(CFIndex i=0; i<count; i++)
{
  CFDictionaryRef dictionary = static_cast<CFDictionaryRef>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(desc, i));
  quint32 id;
  CFNumberGetValue(static_cast<CFNumberRef>(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kCGWindowNumber)),
                   kCFNumberSInt32Type, &id);
  allWindows << id;
}
CFRelease(desc);
CFRelease(windows);
do
{
  QThread::currentThread()->msleep(100);
  windows = CGWindowListCreate(option, id);
  desc = CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(windows);
  count = CFArrayGetCount(desc);
  for(CFIndex i=0; i<count; i++)
  {
    CFDictionaryRef dictionary = static_cast<CFDictionaryRef>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(desc, i));
    quint32 id;
    CFNumberGetValue(static_cast<CFNumberRef>(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kCGWindowNumber)),
                     kCFNumberSInt32Type, &id);
    if(allWindows.contains(id))
      continue;
    QString name = QString::fromCFString(static_cast<CFStringRef>(
                                           CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kCGWindowOwnerName)));
    qCDebug(actOp) << static_cast<CFNumberRef>(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kCGWindowNumber))
                   << " "
                   << static_cast<CFStringRef>(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kCGWindowOwnerName));
    if(name.contains(m_browserTitle))
    {
      m_currentWindow->mac = id;
      qCDebug(actOp) << "window is finded";
      return;
    }
    else
      allWindows << id;
  }
  CFRelease(desc);
  CFRelease(windows);
}
while(m_currentWindow->mac == 0 && !timer.hasExpired(maxTime));
```

I tried to look in the direction of `QWindow`, but could not find how to get `NSView`, for the method `Window::fromWinId`, having only the desired window `CGWindowID`.

Tell me how you would implement such a task. Thanks.